# How do I do the setup to allow myself to create Facebook ad campaigns from Python scripts?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook's documentation on this seems quite scattered and poor. It's a pretty straight forward question but I can't find simple step by step instructions on how to set up permissions to be able to do things with campaigns programmatically in my python scripts.

I have tried both of the following approaches, both of which I have found in Facebooks examples but neither of which work.

The first approach I have tried is this:

```
campaign = Campaign(parent_id='12121212')
campaign.update({
    Campaign.Field.name: 'My Campaign',
    Campaign.Field.objective: Campaign.Objective.link_clicks,
})

campaign.remote_create(params={
    'status': Campaign.Status.paused,
})
```

When I run this though I get an error from this line:

```
'status': Campaign.Status.paused,
```

The error says AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call'.

I have also tried the following different approach:

```
my_app_id = '1212121212121212'
my_app_secret = 'g121g21g2g21g2g12g12'
my_access_token = '12121212121ig2j121kj1j3g1h2kj1h2k1h2j1h2k12hj12h1k21j2h1k2j12k12h1k2jh12k12h1kj2h1k212j1h2k12h1k2jh12kj12h1k2j'
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

me = AdUser(fbid='126712121')
my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts())
print(my_accounts)
my_account = me.get_ad_accounts()[0]

campaign = objects.Campaign(parent_id = my_account.get_id_assured())
campaign[objects.Campaign.Field.name] = "Potato Campain" # sic
campaign[objects.Campaign.Field.configured_status] = objects.Campaign.Status.paused
```

But this gives me an error on the following line:

```
 my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts())
```

The error looks like so:

```
facebookads.exceptions.FacebookRequestError: 

  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/643866195/adaccounts
  Params:  {'summary': 'true'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", 
        "code": 3, 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "fbtrace_id": "Gc2iAi7MwuD"
      }
    }
```

I just wanna get this working, what set up am I missing based on these errors? Thanks and i love you..

Comment: What permissions does your access token include?

Comment: ads_management, user_friends and public_profile @CBroe

Comment: guys im an idiot, changed this line me = AdUser(fbid='126712121') to me = AdUser(fbid='me') and all was well with the world. still stick to my claim that facebook's documentation could have been cuter.